# Evaluating a polynomial in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am currently trying to get better using recursion in prolog. Im not sure why its a bit more difficult for me to grasp than other programming languages. To begin id like to show my code with the results.

```
eval_term([H|T], X, Y):- Y is X^T * H.


eval_poly([],X,Y).
eval_poly([H|T],X,Y):- eval_term(H, X, Y2), eval_poly(T, X, Y2).
eval_poly([H|T],X,Y):- Y is Y2 + Y, eval_poly(T,X,Y).

?- eval_poly([[1|2],[2|1],[3|0]],2, Y).
true .
```

Above I have what I have so far out of a few failed iterations. I give the base case with an empty list followed by what numeric value will replace the variable(X) and the intended output(Y).
The polynomial is structured so that the head of each pair is the coefficient and the tail is the exponent. Y should produce 11 for the provided input but I only seem to get true. Using trace I can see that its able to utilize the eval_term() properly but from there I've been stuck. Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `eval_poly([H|T],X,Y):- Y is Y2 + Y, eval_poly(T,X,Y).` uses `Y2` but never binds it to a value.

Comment: I thought it was binded through the Y variable?

Comment: Only the left side of `is` gets bound (if it isn't already).  Plus, if that clause *did* bind `Y2`, it would always bind it to 0, suggesting that `Y is Y2 + Y` isn't actually accomplishing anything.

Comment: Oh so maybe i replace the Y with Y2?

Comment: `Y2 is Y2 + Y`?  Or `Y is Y2 + Y2`?  I don't see either of these accomplishing anything.

Comment: Remember: unlike in most languages, variables cannot have their values *changed*: once one gets bound, it stays with that value.

Comment: ohhhh I think im starting to get it! Thanks man. Ill try and see what else i can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

To work correctly, your code needs some **changes**:

- When the list representing the polynomial is empty, no matter what the value of the second argument is, the result produced by the predicate `eval_poly/3` must be 0. So you need to change the base case to:

  ```
  eval_poly([], _, 0).
  ```
- Since instantiated variables cannot have their values changed, you need to use a *fresh* variable for each new computed value. So you need to change the recursive case to:

  ```
  eval_poly([H|T], X, Y):-
      eval_term(H, X, Y1),
      eval_poly(T, X, Y2),
      Y is Y1 + Y2.
  ```

Besides the clause defining predicate `eval_term/3`, only these two modified clauses are needed for the predicate `eval_poly/3` to work correctly. However, there are a few points in your code that can be **improved**:

- In Prolog, it's more idiomatic to represent a pair as a term of the form `First-Second`. So you should code predicate `eval_term/3` as:

  ```
  eval_term(Coefficient-Exponent, X, Y):- 
      Y is Coefficient * X^Exponent.
  ```
- Also, for more efficiency, you can get ride of the predicate `eval_term/3` and redefine the predicate `eval_poly/3` using tail recursion and accumulator:

  ```
  eval_poly(Terms, X, Y) :-
      eval_poly_loop(Terms, X, 0, Y).

  eval_poly_loop([], _, Acc, Acc).
  eval_poly_loop([Coefficient-Exponent|Terms], X, Acc, Y):-
      NewAcc is Acc + Coefficient * X^Exponent,
      eval_poly_loop(Terms, X, NewAcc, Y).
  ```
- Running examples:

  ```
  ?- eval_poly([1-2, 2-1, 3-0], 2, Y).         % 1*x^2 + 2*x^1 + 3
  Y = 11.

  ?- eval_poly([2-3, (-5)-1, 3-0], 3, Y).      % 2*x^3 - 5*x + 3
  Y = 42.
  ```